# MySQL / PHP / Doctrine encoding error

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, doctrine-orm

In development I am using a MySQL database on windows with a schema where I set the charset to UTF-8 and the collation to default collation. As O/R-Mapper I am using Doctrine 2. When I am on my windows machine there is no encoding problem of any sort, but as I deployed the code / database to a productive server which runs on linux, an encoding problem popped up: When I take a look at the data inside the tables using MySQL-Workbench, it looks like this

[image: MySQL-Workbench Snapshot]

On the other side, the application just works fine, as there is no encoding problem, but as I update the data using the MySQL-Workbench with some special characters (äöü ...), an encoding problem is then visible on the website.

Comment: What encoding do you have on your files? Are they also in `utf-8`?

Comment: If you mean PHP/HTML-Files then UTF-8.

Comment: I mean all the files.. including the PHP files that fetches things from the database.

Comment: the files are UTF-8 encoded

Comment: Look for "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored